# update a text view to display from array every second

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to build a short memory game and I want a list of words to be shown.

At the start of the activity, the first word, then every second the next word and after the last word is shown the activity changes without user proc. I have tried some things but the closest I've been is just the last word being shown.  Any thoughts?

Java file:

```
 package com.example.pc.myapplication;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.Random;


 public class Game1Round1 extends Activity {


    String[] round1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game1round1);

        round1 =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.round1);

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateTextView();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();


    Proceed();
    }


    private void updateTextView() {
        int i= 0;
        while ( i <13) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomTextView);



            textView.setText(round1[i]);
           i = i + 1;
        }
    }
public void Proceed() {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Game1Start.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
}
```

And my strings.xml:

```
   <resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string-array name="round1">
    <item>Cinnamon</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Milk</item>
    <item>Detergent</item>
    <item>Cheese</item>
    <item>Shampoo</item>
    <item>Butter</item>
    <item>Tangerine</item>
    <item>Coffee</item>
    <item>Marmalade</item>
    <item>Cabbage</item>
    <item>Meat</item>
    <item>Sugar</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: you call `updateTextView` unneccesarily, use time passes properly in thread implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the `updateTextView()` method and change your `Thread` like this

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted() && i < 12) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomTextView)).setText(round1[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                });
            }
            Proceed();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};

t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `run()` method after `try`, `catch` use `finally` and put `proceed()` method in that like below

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

@Override
public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateTextView();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

     finally{ Proceed(); }

        }
 };
```

then you should start the thread

```
t.start();
```

Hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lastCommentText.setText(...);
        }
    }, 1000);
```